# Set cell identifier programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm building a `UITableView` with some cells in it. However, it keeps throwing `unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell`. I'm using the code below, which should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.ninjas[indexPath.row] name];

    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [self.ninjas[indexPath.row] thumbnail]];

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"50-50.jpg"]];

    return cell;
}
```

I'm not using a storyboard for this app.

Comment: Did you assign the cell identifier to a cell in the storyboard?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826383/when-to-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-vs-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifi

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (as opposed to just `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`), one needs to first register that reuse ID with the table view and a reference to the cell class or the xib using one of [these functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

**edit:** also, if you're creating prototype cells with Interface Builder, you'll need to specify a resue ID for those cells as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I should've mentioned this before, but I'm not using a storyboard for this app.

Comment: Then simply registering your `UITableViewCell` for your reuse ID after creating the `UITableView` should solve you problem.