# Assertion failure in > -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I got this error message when trying to `addSubView()` into `UITableViewCell`

Error message

> 2015-05-18 11:26:46.048 xxxxx[1128:437863] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:6245 2015-05-18
>   11:26:46.053 DateTick[1128:437863] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to
>   dequeue a cell with identifier AgeCell - must register a nib or a
>   class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1856982d8 0x196ebc0e4 0x185698198 0x18654ced4 0x18a251e84 0x100094c20 0x100095070 0x18a3d9a68
>   0x18a3cd890 0x18a1b9268 0x18a0d5760 0x189a1de1c 0x189a18884
>   0x189a18728 0x189a17ebc 0x189a17c3c 0x189a11364 0x1856502a4
>   0x18564d230 0x18564d610 0x1855792d4 0x18ed8f6fc 0x18a13efac
>   0x1000c0a9c 0x19753aa08) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

I already declared `AgeCell` inside `UITableViewCell` identifier

[image]

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AgeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell //1

        let slider =  RangeSlider(frame:cell.bounds)
        slider.minimumValue = 1;
        slider.selectedMinimumValue = 2;
        slider.maximumValue = 10;
        slider.selectedMaximumValue = 8;
        slider.minimumRange = 2;
        slider.addTarget(self, action:"updateRangeLabel", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        cell.addSubview(slider)
        return cell
    }
```

P.S: BTW my `UITableViewController` is a static cell, not a dynamic cell.

Comment: Did you [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=must+register+a+nib+or+a+class+for+the+identifier+or+connect+a+prototype+cell+in+a+storyboard)?

Comment: already done in stackoverflow, still not working. already 3 days stuck finding out this error.

Comment: Did you do what the error states? Did you register a cell with the identifier "AgeCell" (case matters)?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax with Swift is

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "AgeCell", bundle: nil)
self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"AgeCell")
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: are different methods.

The documentation says:

> Important: You must register a class or nib file using the
>   registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or
>   registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this
>   method.

[Check out this Q&A.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25826383/77567) for more details about this topic

To register a NIB in swift:

```
UINib nib = UINib.nibWithNibName("AgeCell", bundle:nil);
self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"AgeCell");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your cell's nib with the UITableView.  This way, the UITableView will know that your reuseIdentifier `"AgeCell"` matches the cell.  You usually do this in `viewDidLoad` for your view controller.

In Objective C:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AgeCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"AgeCell"];
}
```

In Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "AgeCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"AgeCell")
}
```

Comment: are you sure UINib nib = UINib.nibWithNibName("AgeCell", bundle:nil); ? is it in swift?

Comment: I've fixed the Swift syntax, thanks to @Joped for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "itemTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! itemTableViewCell

        let item = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = item.name

        return cell
    }
```