# cell.textLabel.text repeats in every section of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm setting up the way `texLabel` of a `UITableViewCell` is determined in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and the problem is that when pulling from `agendaTableArray`, it repeats the item in every section of the table, rather than only in the section it belongs to. In other words, I want each item in the array to be a row in its own section.

Here's how it currently looks:

[image]

Here's how I'm setting up `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    }

    self.agendaTableArray = @[@"Dinner with Rebekah", @"Soccer game", @"Denist appt.", @"Celebrate job offer, drinks with Pierre!", @"No events today!"];

    // Set title of the event
    if (self.datePicked == [NSNumber numberWithInt:16]) {
        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath says self.datePicked is 16");
    }
    else if (self.datePicked == [NSNumber numberWithInt:17]) {
        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath says self.datePicked is 17");
    }
    else if (self.datePicked == [NSNumber numberWithInt:18]) {
        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath says self.datePicked is 18");
    }
    else if (self.datePicked == [NSNumber numberWithInt:19]) {
        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath says self.datePicked is 19");
    }
    else {

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [self whatSectionsAreVisible];

    return cell;
}
```

How can I set it to only load the item from `agendaTableArray` in the first section's cell?

Comment: Can you add your code of  numberofsectionsintableview and numberofrowsinsection

Comment: You are determining the cell title using `indexPath.row`; what you really is some logic involving `indexPath.section`. In each section, the rows start at index `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use this:

```
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

Instead of

```
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
```

Even if is not strictly necessary, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25835438/2091315) is a good explanation of why you should do it.

Second, you're assigning a new array every time a cell is requested to be drawn, and if for any reason you decide to change an element, it won't work, this line should be in your `viewDidLoad` to improve performance:

```
self.agendaTableArray = @[@"Dinner with Rebekah", @"Soccer game", @"Denist appt.", @"Celebrate job offer, drinks with Pierre!", @"No events today!"];
```

Third, you should never compare NSNumber values with a `==`, two NSNumber will be exactly the same (`==`) only if they are really the same object, not the actual value of it, comparing two NSNumber you need to use isEqualToNumber:

```
// Assuming datePicked is a NSNumber
([self.datePicked isEqualsToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16]])
```

Finally to set a different element for each section you should do:

```
// Assuming there's only one element per section.
cell.textLabel.text = self.agendaTableArray[indexPath.section];
```

Comment: That's true, I just think the `forIndexPath` approach is better, I'll modify my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are reusing the cells so, just after

```
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
```

set

```
cell.textLabel.text = nil;
```

Comment: And you are loading that for every cell, if you only want it in he first one, wrap it inside an if statement like this: if(indexPath.row == 0) { }

Answer (score 0):

You can check for which section cellForRowAtIndexPath is in by using :

```
if(indexPath.section==0){ 
//Logic for section 0
}else if(indePath.section==1){
//Logic for section 1
}
```

inside of that if for instance you want the first row of the first section this will do it:

```
if(indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0){ 
   //Code here
}
```

I hope that helps. Of course instead of && you can nest indexPath.row==0 inside of the first if like so:

```
if(indexPath.section==0){ 
  if(indexPath.row==0){
    //Code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First
Set the `agendaTableArray` in a different place like `init`, `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Also I'm guessing you have in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` something like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return N; // the number of sections you want to display
}
```

And `numberOfRowsInSection:`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.agendaTableArray.count;
}
```

Then you may want to compare those numbers maybe like this

```
if ([self.datePicked intValue] == 16) {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath says self.datePicked is 16");
}
```

in which case I recommend to use a `switch` condition

OR as suggested using `isEqualsToNumber:`

Finally take this line

```
cell.textLabel.text = nil;
```

out of the if condition

My suggestion

You may want to create your custom `UITableViewCell` and initialized it with a default cell style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, then override the cell's `prepareForReuse` to reset the content of the reusable cell.

Then in `viewDidLoad` you can register and you can dispose the if condition `if (!cell){...}` this way your code will look more modular and cleaner