# TableViewCells wrong size initially when animating tableView constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` that's top edge is attached to the bottom of a `UIButton`. The `UITableView`'s edges are attached to the edges of the screen.

The `UITableView` has a height constraint that is initially set to `0`, and then when pressing the `UIButton` I animate the height constraint constant to the desired size, effectively expanding the `UITableView` out below the `UIButton`. Tapping the `UIButton` again animates the constant back to `0` collapsing and hiding the `UITableView` again.

The issue I'm having is that on first load/expansion of the `UITableView`, as the cells appear, they do not seem to be the correct width - the right hand end (including its content) seem to expand out slightly. If I collapse the `UITableView` and then re-expand it again, the bug doesn't occur so it only seems to happen on first load of the cells.

I have tried this with both default `Value1` type cells, and also with custom cells from Nibs and the problem occurs with both.

I have also tried calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` and `cell.layoutSubviews()` before `return cell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` but neither have any effect.

**The problem only occurs on iPhone 6 and later**, presumably because the screen got slightly wider from this device. On iPhone 5S and older, the cells load fine first time. It almost seems as if the cells initially load at iPhone 5S and lower width, and then expand outwards on the larger devices.

The problem seems to be something to do with changing the `UITableView`'s height constraint constant value, but I'm not sure why.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Added `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell?

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell!.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14)
    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    cell!.textLabel?.text = self.someArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: show some ur cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: @vaibby Added it above

Comment: check in the storyboard - there is a height for cell setting that can be found when inspecting the tableview. If that isn't 0 (your intended initial height) then you might be getting the error there.

Comment: @Damo Do you mean the 'Row Height' setting? That's the only thing I can find that is similar to what you mean. I just tried setting it to 0, but it defaults to 1 and even still it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: ("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath))
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `TableCell` isn't even a class (at least in my project) and secondly, the cell dequeues and loads fine so this has no effect. In fact, I'm not actually sure I can set the style of the cell to `Value1` this way and so it's actually worse.

Comment: Well the code doesn't even work. `reuseIdentifier` must be a `String` and `("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)` isn't a `String`.

Comment: u mean ("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) isn't a String then how come it doesnt gave any error?

Comment: It does... `Cannot convert value of type '(String, forIndexPath: NSIndexPath)' to expected argument type 'String?'`

Comment: u found any answer for this?  u can see this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892039/animation-with-constraints-in-uitableviewcell-launches-incorrectly/34892374#34892374