# What happens if you don't specific an indexPath when creating a tableView Cell? cellForRowAt()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm curious what happens or if it's bad if you do not include the `for: indexPath` when creating a `UITableViewCell`. For example, here is the standard creation of a cell taken from a basic `UITableViewController`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
```

I'm curious if there would be any negative affects from creating a cell like so:

```
let cellWithoutIndexPath = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Comment: Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000801/14351818), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826383/when-to-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-vs-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifi), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213804/ios-what-is-a-difference-between-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifierfor-and-d)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if you don't include the indexPath there is no way for the cell to know where to go next or what to do. The documentation description for 'IndexPath' is:

"A list of indexes that together represent the path to a specific location in a tree of nested arrays."

If I had an array of fruit that I wanted to populate the tableView with: [apple, orange, pear], the 'indexPath.row' would point out that the first cell should be at location 0 in the array and the second cell should be at location 1, etc.

Another example would be this line of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
```

Had I not included the indexPath, the tableView would not know which cell I want to deselect.