# Unable to load TableView in Today Extension ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I was unable to load a tableview inside today extension. I deleted the initial view controller and replaced it with a tableView controller. Did added the delegates in table view `NCWidgetProviding` and its function `widgetPerformUpdate`. It was just a sample app, to check the today extension. Can anybody respond with a solution !!!

Thanks
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Few things I noticed:

1. try setting tableView's delegate and datasource in `viewDidLoad()`:

   ```
   self.tableView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.dataSource = self
   ```
2. it's better to use `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with `indexPath`:

   ```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   ```

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25835438/2374802)

If none of the above helps, maybe there's something wrong with autolayout? Table might be displayed, it's just not visible.

Comment: hey thanks for the response... however I'm not getting any output ... constraint are all fine... Could you please tell me what is the role of framework in between extension and the app

Comment: still I'm getting "Unable to load" alert in extension... I did deleted default view controller from extension storyboard and added new tableView controller to it. Does this influence the issue

Answer (score 0):

When you replace the default view controller in the storyboard, you need to check "Is Initial View Controller" in the Attributes Inspector.

[image]