# two tableviews with two different tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two tableviews with two different custom tableview cells.. and am doing this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == self.tableview {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "matchescell") as! MatchesTableViewCell
        // ......
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filtercell") as! FilterTableViewCell
        // ......
        return cell
    }
}
```

and of course i have registered them both from storyboard...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but i keep getting this:

[image]

on this line:

> let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filtercell") as! FilterTableViewCell

tried to register them like this:

```
   tableview.register(MatchesTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "matchescell")

   filterdrop.register(FilterTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "filtercell")
```

but still getting the same error!

What am doing wrong?!

Comment: What's the full error message in console? You missed a step. But it could be because you didn't registered the class, you didn't registered the xib (if it's in a custom xib), you didn't set the correct class/identifier in the cell property, etc.

Comment: @Larme i did! and double checked that! :(

Comment: Show us the line where you are registering the xib's

Comment: @Nitish just updated my question

Comment: check my answer, you just made a typing mistake.

Comment: If no extra nib is used and the cells are designed in Interface Builder you **must not** register the cells in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you typed "tableview" instead of "tableView" in your else part:

replace :

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filtercell") as! FilterTableViewCell
```

with :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filtercell") as! FilterTableViewCell
```

It is crashing because your "tableview" doesn't have this cell registered.

Comment: OMG!!! Yes that was the problem! i can't believe it!! :| lol anyways, many thanks!!!!

Comment: lol, this is one of the reason that let me never create a reference to a UITableView with tableview name :D

Answer (score 0):

Add the "filtercell" identifier in the storyboard or xib custom cell (FilterTableViewCell).

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause:

- You haven't registered the class or the nib of the cell to the proper tableview
- You haven't set the identifier in the cellview in you nib/storyboard
- You have inverted the tableview and their cell type

Comment: Please add the cell registration in your post. Then try a run and debug which of the 2 type of cell is nil before you return it

Comment: just did .. and the nil is the filtercell

Comment: Ok, so, try to understand if, removing the delegate from the table filterdrop table, the other one work correctly. Let's see if the problem is only that table or we are missing somethign

Comment: yes exactly, removed delegates from filter tableview .. the other tableview works fine without errors

Comment: You created a xib for the cell views or you create the cell inside their table? Can you provide the xib or the storyboard vc?

Comment: I have created the cell inside their tableview ... i found the answer .. it was a typo x_x wrote tableview other than tableView and everything is solved!! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This because you either didn't register the cell

```
tableView.register(CustomCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellID")
```

//

```
 tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellClass", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellID")
```

or you swapped the dequeuing line for the tables

Comment: i do this inside cellForRowAt? or in viewdidload?

Comment: I tried this .. but still didn't work .. getting the same error :(

Comment: In the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into your Tableview controller in the Storyboard. You should have another indentier than called in:

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "filtercell") as! FilterTableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you should always use this newer function

```
dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)
```

instead of

```
dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826383/when-to-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-vs-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifi) for details.

Comment: Mmmh, you need to call the new function if you have different kind of size for the tableviewcell I think

Comment: @MarkWarriors: Nope, not really. Cell sizing is done either dynamically (`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`) or via the delegate method `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`. This is independent of how you dequeue the cell(s).

Comment: yep, I know, but if all your cell have the same height and width, the "new function" is pretty useless, because is useless for the application search the size of the cell at that index.. because is the same size of the others

Answer (score -1):

You can easily solve this problem just to check what tableview you use at that time.
you can try this code,

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if (tableview == (yourtableview 1)) {

let cell = yourtableview 1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourtableview Cell 1") as? yourtableview  Cell 1

// write your code for tableview 1
return cell
}

else
{
 let cell = yourtableview 2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourtableview  Cell 2") as? yourtableview  Cell 2

// write your code for tableview 2
return cell
}

}